# Open Pdf at Previous Page Number where it user left

Tags: java, android, pdf-viewer

I am tring to open  the recent pdf file at page number from firebase How to Pick Up Reading Where User Left it.
I am Creating a Model Class of Mutiple PDF book and fetch online.
how i can open the recent page that i left in firebase.

```
public class ModelPdf implements Parcelable {

private String images;
private String name;
private String url;

public ModelPdf() {
}



public ModelPdf(String images, String name, String url) {
    //parameterized constructor 
}

protected ModelPdf(Parcel in) {
    images = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ModelPdf> CREATOR = new Creator<ModelPdf>() {
    @Override
    public ModelPdf createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ModelPdf(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ModelPdf[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ModelPdf[size];
    }
};
 // rest getter and setter methods of class attribute 

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(images);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some more information

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://localhost/11zon/android/android_shared_preferences.php) to store current page value and then use it.